# Embedded Postgres does not work on Mac OS Ventura M1

Tags: postgresql, macos

Embedded Postgres does not work on Mac OS Ventura M1, it gives an error

```
Process [/var/folders/vs/pfsp79pn1rgcc038_4yvsfk00000gn/T/embedded-pg/PG-578c3302bce806451b07e3a73d8438d1/bin/initdb, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, /var/folders/vs/pfsp79pn1rgcc038_4yvsfk00000gn/T/epg16251203664783330327, -E, UTF-8] failed
```

, when launched in the console it gives that

```
/var/folders/vs/pfsp79pn1rgcc038_4yvsfk00000gn/T/embedded-pg/PG-578c3302bce806451b07e3a73d8438d1/bin/postgres ; exit;
zsh: segmentation fault
```

Can anyone come across?

Tried to reinstall postgres, did commands with link and so on